# how to install pycurl 7.43 at ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-18.04, pycurl

Help me, all
I have some error while installation of pycurl on ubuntu 18,04
I tried follow as:

```
apt-cache depends python-pycurl

sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

apt-cache search gnutl | grep dev

sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev

sudo apt install python-pycurl

pip install pycurl
```

but, failed to install.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please paste the errors that you got when trying those commands?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That means 'No such Python.h while compiling pycurl.h'.

Comment: That means, 'Not found files such as python.h while compiling pycurl.h'. For now, my server is closed.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python3.8-dev
```

and by referring to these links [Error in installation pycurl 7.19.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669428/error-in-installation-pycurl-7-19-0), https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/596.
In addtion, my python version is 3.8, so I installed python3.8-dev.